# inner class meta field as a variable to be used

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have an inner class `Meta` inside one of my models. I wish to use this attribute later-on in one of my functions. How can I use this without explicitly specifying the name of the `db_table` ? I want this to be able to trivially extend child-classes that call the same function without over-riding the method every time.

Using `self._meta.db_table.objects.all()` throws an error saying that self has no `_meta` attribute. Find code sample below :

```
class ViewSetDef(ModelViewSet):
    """Provide the /defined_search/ endpoints."""

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer

    class Meta:                     # pylint: disable=W0232,C1001
        db_table = DefSearch

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DefSearch.objects.all()
        # return self._meta.db_table.objects.all()
```

## child-class extending from above

```
class InfoViewSetDef(ViewSetDef):
    """Provide the /defined_search/ endpoints."""

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = InfoViewSet

    class Meta:                     # pylint: disable=W0232,C1001
        db_table = InfoViewDefSearch

    # I'm over-riding get_queryset because I dont know how to 
    def get_queryset(self):
        return InfoViewDefSearch.objects.all()
        # return self._meta.db_table.objects.all()
```

EDIT after reading Daniel's clarifying comment below :

I'd like to be able to specify a class as any entity X inside a Viewset and then define the function as : f(x) = X.objects.all(). I thought I could use it inside class Meta and call it, but apparently not. Can you suggest some other options to do so ? Is models.ForeignKey the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing models and viewsets here. Viewsets don't have a Meta attribute.

And in any case, on a model, `db_table` is a string that defines the name of the table in the database; it's not something you can call `objects.all()` on.

Comment: I'd like to be able to specify a class as any entity X inside a Viewset and then define the function as : f(x) = X.objects.all(). I thought I could use it inside class Meta and call it, but apparently not. Can you suggest some other options to do so ? Is models.ForeignKey the best way to do this ?